# Make some route info persistent on RHEL

Tags: linux, linux-networking, route

I would like to make the following route info persistent.

I know how to do it for the default, but how about this line:

```
10.27.74.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0



Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.27.74.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
default         10.27.74.253    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 2):

You create a file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`

And add the following:

`10.x.x.x/y via 10.x.x.x`

Where `10.x.x.x/y` is the IP or subnet you want to route and `10.x.x.x` is the gateway for that subnet.

You then restart your network or disable/enable eth0 and it should automatically bring up your static route.

Answer (score 0):

The most compatible way is to create a route file under /etc/sysconfig/network-script and to specify here the desired route.

In your case, create the file /etc/sysconfig/network-script/route-eth0 and put into it the following directive: `10.27.74.0/8 via 10.27.74.253`
After that, issue the command `service network restart`

This setup works both with and without NetworkManager. You can read more [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_Command_Line_Interface.html#sec-Configuring_Static_Routes_in_ifcfg_files) and [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html#sec-Configuring_Static_Routes_Using_nmcli).